# I can't get in-coming changes from my team member and also they can't get in changes from my side plasticSCM cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

I have applied subtractive merge to one of my changesets and after it, I guess I didn't check in my work. After that, I faced problems that I can't check in my work even if I couldn't get any incoming changes.
after applying some different solutions, Now I can check in my work but couldn't receive any incoming changes, not even my team member can get any changes from my side.
If anybody would help me to understand the issue I am facing, it will help me to resume my work.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure what a _"subtractive"_ merge is but I find this question as confusing as your other two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189440/in-subtractive-merge-changeset-when-i-clicked-red-dotted-lines-it-shows-merge-li) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177621/i-cant-get-new-changesincoming-changes-even-cant-check-in-my-work).

Comment: Please contact support@codicesoftware.com with a clear description of your problem, the 3 questions you present are probably just 1 issue and could use some clarification. The plasticSCM support Team can even schedule short calls to avoid confusing emails.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Thank you for your reply. Yes, I contacted with Plastic SCM team and I found the solution. because of subtractive submerge the branch changeset lost its links to the main branch. so need to merge them with the main. The same process needs to be done with the changeset of my team member. So now we can check in our work and get incoming changes.